# Excel VBA format footer that contains calculated value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a macro for my footer that uses the RIGHT and LEN function to pull strings from various cells within the worksheet. I've tested on various sheets and this works.

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = Right(Range("D11"), 8) + Right(Range("D4"), Len(Range("D4")) - 24)
```

I did my homework and went with the 'record macro' method to format the footer and came up with the following:

```
 ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Times New Roman,Regular"
```

I do not know how to combine the two without losing my values or getting a compiling error.

Comment: Do they have to be combined? Try leaving them as individual commands on separate lines. One will run after the other is complete.

Comment: When I apply the code as individual commands on separate lines, I either get a blank footer or I get the footer in it's default Arial 10 pt font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah it's looking for quotation marks, like this -

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Algerian,Bold" & """" & Left(Range("A44"), 7) + " " & Mid(Range("B44"), 4, 11)
```

For you -

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Times New Roman,Regular" & """" & Right(Range("D11"), 8) + Right(Range("D4"), Len(Range("D4")) - 24)
```

Comment: @dasMetzger this should do it

Comment: this works!  did not need the extra & """" at the end though. do you know why this was looking for those quotes?  i dont have enough rep to upvote you. but thanks

Comment: @dasMetzger something about it wanting a string, like you'd see if you recorded the macro it would do `"&""font""what you typed"`

Comment: while troubleshooting i was trying to put the entire RIGHT formula into the quotes, but obviously ended up getting nothing in return by the physical characters in the formula.

Comment: Yeah, since VBA `""` is technically a **"** in regular excel, you need """"